# A better alternative to ROW_NUMBER to retrieve a single record per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

We are building a data warehouse where we want to capture the price of every single product and keep this data by day. There is a table with the `FromDate` and the `ToDate`, both of which can have `NULL`'s.

The logic to find todays price is:

1. Ignore any records where the `FromDate` is in the future.
2. Ignore any records where the `ToDate` is in the past.
3. Where there are multiple records that satisfy the above, we want to get the price where the `FromDate` is the most recent and the `ToDate` is the closest to the current date.
4. The system allows duplicates for the same `FromDate` and `ToDate`, so we then order by the primary key descending (newest first).

To tackle this problem, I've used a `ROW_NUMBER` with a `PARTITION` to order the records, and only get the first one. This is working, however it is taking around 20 minutes per day (and hitting `tempdb` quite hard) as we have about 2 million records that will be created from this query.

Are there any better alternatives that may increase the performance of the query?

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1cce/2)

Note that the fiddle is an overly simplified example of the data and only contains relevant parts for this question.

Comment: Do you have any index on the table?

Comment: Yes, indexes aren't my problem. I'm more wandering if there is a way to do this without using analytical functions. Something that will be kinder to `tempdb` perhaps. It's possible that this is the best way, and due to the volume of data I have, I may have to live with it.

Comment: [**This**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT ProductId, @PriceDate AS PriceDate, Price
FROM (SELECT fp.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId
                                ORDER BY COALESCE(FromDate, '19000101') DESC, COALESCE(ToDate, '21000101') ASC) AS RowNumber
      FROM FactPrices fp
      WHERE (FactPrices.FromDate IS NULL OR FactPrices.FromDate <= @PriceDate) AND
            (FactPrices.ToDate IS NULL OR FactPrices.ToDate >= @PriceDate)
     ) A
WHERE A.RowNumber = 1;
```

The `where` clause is a big-time performance killer.  I am going to suggest adding two computed columns and then two more indexes.

The computed columns are:

```
FromDateNotNull as (coalesce(FromDate, '19000101'))
ToDateNotNull as (coalesce(ToDate, '21000101'))
```

Then, create indexes on:

```
(Prices, FromDateNotNull desc, ToDateNotNull asc)
(FromDateNotNull, ToDateNotNull)
```

Then, write the query as:

```
SELECT ProductId, @PriceDate AS PriceDate, Price
FROM (SELECT fp.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId
                                ORDER BY FromDateNotNull DESC, ToDateNotNull
                              ) AS RowNumber
      FROM FactPrices fp
      WHERE FromDateNotNull <= @PriceDate AND
            ToDateNotNull >= @PriceDate
     ) A
WHERE A.RowNumber = 1;
```

Comment: Will give it a try! The source data gets dumped through SSIS so I could remove the NULL's on the way in.

Comment: @Lock . . . Avoiding `or` in the `where` clause will allow the query query to use indexes for the query.

Comment: I rejigged my query to remove all `OR`'s and it is 33 seconds now. Thanks!!